# Call batch files to run on server side

Tags: php, android, batch-file, wamp

I'm building an application using android SDK, which involves a data process procedure: android side making an request to the server for downloading a file from Internet, store in server space and then using a batch file to process the file.

I already wrote the batch script and put on my server (WAMP server for windows), now how do i trigger my batch file to run ?  either using php script or java

And I have some parameters need to pass from android device to the batch file , how do I implement that ?

Comment: You can execute with parameters this way (with PHP certainly, you can't execute server program from the client with JS...): `shell_exec('ls -lart');`

Comment: it didnt work, i used php to call batch file but nothing happened :(

Comment: It may be disabled in the configuration.